# UWP FolderPicker grant access to all sub-paths

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am using a `FolderPicker` in my Windows universal app to have the user choose a directory, and when they've done that I need to access several different files at known subpaths below that directory. I can choose the directory fine, but when I try to access things at subpaths from there I am still denied access. Is there any way to grant access to multiple files in a parent directory without having the force the user to manually select each file that needs to be accessed?

Here is my code that opens the folder picker and adds the chosen directory to my future access list:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null) {
       StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("GitDirectory", folder);
       PathTextBox.Text = folder.Path;
       this.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;
}
```

(apologies for my naming conventions, I'm new to the Win/C# world so I'm writing in a hodge-podgey way I know)

Here is the code in another class that tries to access a sub path. You can assume that the variable `GitDirectory` has been previously assigned the result of calling `FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("GitDirectory");` because it has:

```
StorageFile iniFile = await GitDirectory.GetFileAsync(@"datafiles\i18n\en_US.ini");
IniData data = iniParser.ReadFile(iniFile.Path);
```

It is this final line that finally throws this exception:
`Access to the path 'E:\Documents\git\asirra\datafiles\i18n\en_US.ini' is denied.`

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Have you tried broadfilesystemaccess ?

Comment: I could use that as this is an application for personal use and I won't be submitting it to the Windows store, however since I'm using it as a learning experience I'd like to understand the proper way to do the things I'm trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that when you have access to a file via a `StorageFile` instance at a arbitrary location (user-chosen), you need to use this specific instance to work with the file. You cannot access the file directly by accessing its path (`file.Path`).

I have checked the `IniParser` source code on GitHub and found out you can use the [`IniDataParser` API](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/blob/development/src/IniFileParser/Parser/IniDataParser.cs) instead, for example the following method:

```
IniData Parse(StringReader stringReader)
```

You could read the `ini` file, and then pass it to the parser:

```
var iniFile = await GitDirectory.GetFileAsync(@"datafiles\i18n\en_US.ini");
var text = await FileIO.ReadAllTextAsync(iniFile);
var parser = new IniDataParser();
var data = parser.Parse(text);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation, I'll try it when I get a chance later and mark your answer as approved then.